# Does Java's TimerTask only work with short periods of time?

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-pendingintent, timertask

I am writing this code for android that will allow me to send a message at a certain time on a button click (send). To do this I made a class that implements TimerTask so the code runs when specified. This works for short intervals of time like from 5 minutes to an hour but when I set the code to run after an hour, it will not execute. I am not sure if I am coding something wrong or if this is a common problem but I would like to know if there is a workaround to this.

Relevant Code:

```
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isEmpty(message)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                sendMessageAt();
            }
        }
    });

public void sendMessageAt(){

    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try {
            date = dateFormatter.parse(getDateTime());
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask executeCode = new Execute();
            timer.schedule(executeCode,date); 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your message will be sent at: "+getDateTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public class Execute extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String phoneNm="2017257831";
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        String mesToStr = message.getText().toString();


        sendSMS(phoneNm,mesToStr);
    }

}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNm,String message){


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNm,null,message,pi,null);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android, for long running timer tasks you are better off using the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).Otherwise if your app is not in the foreground it may be 'killed' by the system.